# Dynamically get all .SVC file names using C#

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration-files

i am working on WCF with C#, got requirement to configure all WCF services list in configuration file. Instead of adding manually want it dynamically while loading project. Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

To enumerate all files with given pattern you may try the following code:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles("~", "*.svc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: then use `Directory.GetFiles()` and remove `ToList()`